# How does APC uses memory?

Tags: php, apc

APC is using a lot of memory.
On my server, ~30 Wordpress and 6 Magento websites, it is using more than 1GB wich is more than the size of PHP files.

I thought opcode would be smaller than the PHP files. As is a compiled JAVA compared to source.

For example, the index.php of Magento is 2571B on the disk and it uses 16560B in APC.

I don't use any user cache.

Any idea ?

Comment: Generally speaking, bytecode is not necessarily smaller than source code. Depending on bytecode format and source programming language, there is a lot of metadata and individual operations take many opcodes to implement. However, even if the bytecode is larger, it will not be anywhere that large.

Comment: For what it's worth, I saw pretty comparable APC memory usage when running ~30 separate installations of my application.  I modified my application so that all ~30 sites could share a single codebase (reducing my memory usage ~30x)

Comment: @delan Why don't you posted this as an answer ? I think this is the key. Opcode could be bigger than real code because one php instruction is converted into many opcodes.

Answer (score 2):

The opcode caches each and every php file by the path that it's on.  So that's 30 x every wordpress PHP file or 6 x each Magento PHP file.  That's not to mention any PEAR libraries or others you might be using.

Also, what is your setting in your /etc/php.d/apc.ini or php.ini file for the memory to allow APC?

```
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.shm_size=256
```

Multiply segments times size and thats as large as APC will grow.  It immediately takes this memory block to use, even if you're not really using it.  Check your apc.php file to see the actual usage.

Looking at a Wordpress recent install of wordpress, I'm seeing at least 8M of just php files.   So if you have 30 sites with their own full install of wordpress and using APC, that alone (without any plugins) would be a huge amount of stuff in the opcode cache.

In general opcode should be smaller than the file size, but you can't know for sure 100%.  For example, checking APC.php in the system cache tab, I see this file being cached: `/usr/share/pear/Zend/View/Abstract.php`. I know on disk it is 33k, but APC reports it's using 20K of memory.    If I had 2 copies of this file in two locations (like `/usr/share/pear/Zend/View/Abstract.php` and `/usr/share/pear/Zend2/View/Abstract.php`) and referenced both in different blocks of code, APC would cache each--it thinks they're different files.

Comment: I'm not using shm but mmap memory. I allowed 2048M (apc.shm_size=2048M) and it is 50% used.

Comment: @bokan  can you verify via the apc.php page that you're using no user cache?  I've setup wordpress at times to use cache plugins that can point to APC.  Those plugins store to the user cache.

Comment: "I don't use any user cache." I checked it whit pac.php. You seems to think that my APC is not running properly. Do you have a server to compare to, can you give me the numbers please ? (number of websites, type, amount of cache used by APC..).

Comment: @bokan i think its running fine, just caching a lot of php files.  Using the apc.php page you can see whats in your system cache explicitly.

Comment: @bokan Under the System Cache entries tab on the apc.php page you can see the exact usage by file being cached.  You have to log into the page in order to see the full path of the file being cached.  It will also give you the total count of files being cached.

Comment: I understand what files are cached. I just don't understand how opcode could be 4 times bigger than its sourcecode. (I edited the question to give an example). APC is curently caching 8808 files for 1.2GB

Comment: Thank you Ray, for the time spent on this question.